# Find Columns which starts with Lowercase letters in SQL Server Data Base and list them as a SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

i am trying to Select All Columns in a Database Which Started With Lower Case Letters . Like  'status'.

i Wrote a Command As Below :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 1) = 's'
```

I Got The First Letter And Checked It IF IT's Equal To LowerCase 's' . But It Returns All Column Name's With 's' and 'S' .
i even Tried This :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 1) = LOWER('s')
```

But It Is Like Last one too .

'S' is for Example . i need it for all letters .

Thanks ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the names in `information_schema` tables are case insensitive.  So, your attempt will not just find lower case.

That leaves you with two options.  One is to fiddle with collations to get an equivalent case-sensitive collation.

The other is to use the `ascii()` function:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where ascii(left(column_name, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a8e959d4096e7826961a8ab7e8c0c3f) is a db<>fiddle illustrating the difference.